# Issue with java.io.FileNotFoundExeption

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a problem with a program that I am building that saves test results to a file on my school's local drive. The problem is, when I try to save test results to a file that I choose with a JFileChooser, the program throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException. Here is the code for my method that serializes test results to a file.

```
@Override
        public void testEnded() {
            start.setEnabled(true);
            pause.setEnabled(false);
            end.setEnabled(false);
            results.setVisible(false);
            panel.setVisible(false);
            cheatSheet.setEnabled(true);
            tableTest.setEnabled(true);
            TestEntryEvent event = new TestEntryEvent(name, panel.getCorrectCount(), panel.getIncorrectCount());

            if(panel.getTotalCount() == 158) {
                LinkedList<TestEntry> entries = new LinkedList<TestEntry>();
                TestEntry entry = new TestEntry(event.getName(), event.getCorrect(), event.getIncorrect());
                ObjectInputStream ois = null;
                File file;

                if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainFrame.this, "This test has been completed with " + panel.getCorrectCount() + " questions correct out of " + panel.getTotalCount() + "\nWould you like to save the results?", "Test Completed", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    if(chooser.showSaveDialog(MainFrame.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                            try {
                                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                            } catch (EOFException e) {

                            }

                            try {
                                if(ois != null) {
                                    entries = (LinkedList<TestEntry>)ois.readObject();
                                }
                            } catch (EOFException e) {

                            }
                            if(entries == null) {
                                entries = new LinkedList<TestEntry>();
                            }
                            entries.add(entry);

                            if(ois != null) {
                                ois.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "An error occurred! This was the message: " + e1.getClass());
                        }
                        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                            oos.writeObject(entries);

                            oos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "An error occurred! This was the message: " + e.getClass());
                        }
                    }
                }

                control.addTestEntry(entry);
                testTable.refresh();
                control.deleteEntries();
            }

            if(panel.getTotalCount() < 158) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "You did not complete all questions on the test!", "Test Incomplete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            panel.setCorrectCount(0);
            panel.setIncorrectCount(0);
            panel.setTotalCount(0);

            panel.setCorrectLabel("Correct: " + panel.getCorrectCount());
            panel.setIncorrectLabel("Incorrect: " + panel.getIncorrectCount());

            testing = false;

            roots.clear();
        }
```

When I create a file on the local drive of my school's network where I can serialize the test results to, and run the test on the same computer and serialize the test results, then it works and the file is found! However, when I use a different computer to run the program and serialize results to the local drive file that I created on another computer, it gives me a java.io.FileNotFoundException. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());` Why not just use the actual file? `file = chooser.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: Because I was checking for any possible solution to the problem, I did that before.

Comment: `new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName())` != `chooser.getSelectedFile()`. The first one does not contain any of the directory information from the selected file.

Comment: You're right, I'll change that back. But I've already tried the program on the school computer with that code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Besides using the file from the chooser directly instead of the name, what line number throws the exception (is it the input or output stream)? Can you show the results of file.toString()?

Comment: The problem is, I can't answer your question until tomorrow when I test it at school again. I hope I can get back to you after I try it again there. Then I'll tell you what line threw the exception. In the meanwhile, is there anything wrong with setting file equal to chooser.getSelectedFile()?

Comment: Remember, the exception only shows up when I try to run the program on a different computer than the one that made the file that I serialize results to.